# in javascript,can we match a string with circulate part by using regex but don't split it

Tags: javascript, regex

a string like this: `"01A123,02A13334,03A99313,01BA9424,……"`
substring's regex is: `/\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*/`

can we write a regex to match this string without split it?

Comment: You just did, what is the question?

Comment: You can validate the entire line if need be. Just extend it to `/^\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*(?:,\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*)*$/`

Comment: I think the English was poor, but if you re-read it (i.e `circulate` part), its obvious he was asking to extend it to the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate the entire line is of this form, something like this

```
 #  /^\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*(?:,\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*)*$/

 ^                             # Beginning of string
 \d{2} [A-Z]{1,2} \d*          # 2 digits, 1-2 A-Z, optional 0-many digits
 (?:                           # Cluster group start (non-capture group)
      ,                             # comma ','
      \d{2} [A-Z]{1,2} \d*          # 2 digits, 1-2 A-Z, optional 0-many digits
 )*                            # Cluster group end, optional 0-many times
 $                             # End of string
```

Comment: oops!I don't understand but it work!

Comment: sorry,what does " ?: " means?

Comment: @Deryckxie - `(?: ... )` means non-capture group, `( ... )` means capture group. They are the same, one captures, one doesn't. I added some comments in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
"01A123,02A13334,03A99313,01BA9424".match(/\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*/g);
["01A123", "02A13334", "03A99313", "01BA9424"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can Your regex `\d{2}[A-Z]{1,2}\d*`  can be represented as,

[image]